# Why document.cookie is not working

Tags: javascript

```
  var curCookie = name + "=" + value +
    "; expires=" + ATS_getExpire()  +
    "; path=" + path  +
    "; domain=" + domain  ;     
document.cookie = curCookie;
alert("Your Cookie : " + document.cookie);
```

When i use above code the alert message coming as empty. Why document.cookie is coming as empty.
Please anybody answer.

Comment: Why document.cookie not working with custom path? See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429234/javascript-document-cookie-not-working-with-custom-path

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See here for a [Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TaAtQ/3/)

You're using `;` instead of `,`.

Use `,` to deliminate your cookie values

```
var curCookie = name + "=" + value + 
    ", expires=" + ATS_getExpire() + 
    ", path=" + path + 
    ", domain=" + domain;

document.cookie = curCookie;
alert("Your Cookie : " + document.cookie);
```

**UPDATE**

As of today (2021-08-25), the live example is not consistent accross browsers:

- Chrome 92.0.4515.159: ❌
- Edge 92.0.902.78: ❌
- Opera 77.0.4054.277: ❌
- Firefox 91.0.2: ✅

Comment: can someone explain why this is better? MDN uses ';'

Comment: it is not working for document.cookie = "vcrcjode=118b11a9b3, expires=Sat, 02 Nov 2013 21:23:59 GMT, path=/";

Comment: I think doing it this way makes all of that part of the value, so you're no longer setting the expires, path, and domain properties; you're just setting a value that includes those strings in it. At least that's what Chrome's dev tools are showing me when I try it.

Comment: This is wrong, you're setting all those afte a , as the value and not setting expires, path nor domain.

Comment: The live example is not working in Chrome 92.0.4515.159.

Comment: did anyone find any solution? I tried ; but its not setting cookie at all and if I use , then it sets whole thing as string to cookie instead of setting attributes.

Answer (score 9):

I found that ... frustratingly, document.cookie doesn't work when running the page locally in one's browser.

When I uploaded the same page to a website, suddenly all the cookie values worked just fine.  I will find out why this is and fill the rest of this answer out later.

Comment: Could it be you run the page in a dev server on localhost:3000 white you're trying to contact a backend on localhost:80 or something? Browsers treat this as cross-origin.

Comment: You could also experience cookie issues if your localhost SSL cert isn't valid.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes this can occur if the page is hosted on a domain listed on the [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/learn/) (e.g. github.io, cloudfront.net).  These domains are treated specially by the browser and restrict writing cookies for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Try using jQuery Cookie plugin:

[jQuery Cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```