# Set Cookie Path JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies, cookie-path

I want the code below to set the path to root, I understand I have to set / as the path value however this is not my code and I am not familiar with Javascript!

```
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure){

document.cookie= name + "=" + escape(value) +
((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
}
```

I have tried editing the code as below but have been unsuccessful.

```
 setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure){

document.cookie= name + "=" + escape(value) +
((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
((path) ? "; path="/") +
((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
}
```

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551113/how-to-set-path-while-saving-the-cookie-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 14, accepted):

change to this

```
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure){
    document.cookie= name + "=" + escape(value) +
    ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
    ("; path=/") +       //you having wrong quote here
    ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
    ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
}
```

Comment: I am receiving a syntax error...
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: @HarrisonBrace sorry for that, this time will be OK

Comment: how can i set the path in cookie in nodejs(on server side) ?