# Javascript document.cookie not working with custom path

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

The following statement working and it setting the cookie.

```
document.cookie = "vcrcjode=118b11a9b3; expires=Sat, 
                   02 Nov 2013 21:23:59 GMT; path=/";
```

But the same statement with different path not working.

```
document.cookie = "vcrcjode=118b11a9b3; 
                   expires=Sat, 02 Nov 2013 21:23:59 GMT; path=/tag/";
```

Both statement not generating any errors. Why second statement not working?

Comment: path does not exist? is there a `tag` dir?

Comment: "is there a tag dir"? is it a real problem?. I dont think browser check for that. And yes /tag/ dir do exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i tested above code i was testing from Console in Google Chrome.

Both statement is setting the cookie but it only show in console when we navigate to /tag/ directory.