# Laravel $_COOKIE is not working in any browser except chrome

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cookies, laravel-8

I created a dark and light mode in my laravel project and whenever the vue JS toggle is clicked it should create a cookie that saves the value. It works perfectly fine on google chrome but when i tried it on edge and firefox it showed (Undefined array key "isDarkModeOn").

I just want this cookie to be saved to any browser

My toggle Vue component which includes create cookie

```js
<template>
    <div
        class="flex cursor-pointer items-center justify-between"
        @click="store.modeToggle(), modeToggle()"
    >
        <div
            class="flex h-4 w-12 items-center rounded-full bg-gray-300 p-1 duration-300 ease-in-out"
            :class="{ 'bg-green-400': store.toggleActive }"
        >
            <div
                class="h-3 w-3 transform rounded-full bg-white shadow-md duration-300 ease-in-out"
                :class="{ 'translate-x-7': store.toggleActive }"
            ></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { store } from "./store.js";
export default {
    props: ["theme"],
    data() {
        return {
            store,
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        if (this.theme === "false") {
            store.light();
        } else {
            store.dark();
        }
    },
    methods: {
        dark() {
            this.$emit("dark");
        },
        light() {
            this.$emit("light");
        },

        modeToggle() {
            if (
                this.darkMode ||
                document.querySelector("body").classList.contains("dark")
            ) {
                this.light();
            } else {
                this.dark();
            }
            const isDarkModeOn = store.toggleActive;
            createCookie("isDarkModeOn", isDarkModeOn.toString(), 60 * 60 * 24);
        },
    },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

my Js file which contains the logic for creating the cookie

```js
function createCookie(name, value, timeInSeconds) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + timeInSeconds * 1000);
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();

    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    let name = cname + "=";
    let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    let ca = decodedCookie.split(";");
    for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        let c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == " ") {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

window.onload = function () {
    const isDarkModeOn = getCookie("isDarkModeOn");
    if (isDarkModeOn === "true") document.body.classList.add("dark");
};
```

and this is how I tell browser to display dark class or hide it according to the cookie if it exists

```html
<body id="app" style="font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif" class="scroll-smooth {{ $_COOKIE[('isDarkModeOn')] === 'true' ? 'dark' : '' }}">
```

It works on chrome but not on any other browser.

Also when testing in Laravel like this

```html
        @if ($value = $_COOKIE['isDarkModeOn'])
            {{ $value }}
        @else
            'not found'
        @endif
```

It echos the value not problem so since there is a cookie why any other browser can't identify it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why document.cookie is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774848/why-document-cookie-is-not-working)

Comment: The variable is server side, it doesnt depend on the browser you are using. your issue is related on how you set your cookie in your javascript

Comment: Yes YESS! You're right. I removed everything about the cookie from php blade file and my site opened normally on edge and then i put this back again it still works. when i clear the cookies It doesn't work again. so it means that my cookie is called in blade before browser create and store the cookie therefor it can't read it. how can i set the cookie at the same time my browser boots until my Javascript updates it according to the toggle then?

Comment: testing the value in a way that doesnt trigger an error. check the answer

Comment: Also the thread you shared has nothing to do with my question. I tried to change that and it solved nothing the issue isn't in the ',' or ';' at all. it's in the cookie that only gets created after php loads therefore the browser can't reach to the point of it's creation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue is solved by adding the below lines of code before the body

```html
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE['isDarkModeOn'])) {
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['isDarkModeOn'];
} else {
    $cookie = '';
}

?>
```

Not the best way to do it but It did the trick

Answer (score 0):

As for your test, you should use something more safe (doesnt trigger an error when absent)

```
@if (isset($_COOKIE['isDarkModeOn']))
    {{ $_COOKIE['isDarkModeOn'] }}
@else
    'not found'
@endif
```

Comment: Issue is not in my test issue is I'm using the cookie to trigger specific theme. So i need a way to create the cookie as soon as my browser boot with default value and then change it later with JS